# How do I call a method with a generic type T[] as an argument?

Tags: java

Ok, say I have this method header:
`public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void qSort(T[] a, int p, int q)`

Say I wanted T[] a to hold {5,2,7,3,8,9}. How would I create this T[] a and how would I call this method if I wanted to test it? I'm a little confused.

I've tried updating my question to make it more clear. If something isn't clear then please post a comment.

Anything?

Comment: You can't use primitives with generics.

Comment: what do you mean by 'main'?

Comment: i meant main method. scratch that then. How would I call this method which is inside a certain class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first:  you can't use a primitive array to hold elements that are expected in an object array; they're incompatible types.

Remember that the generic type parameter `T` is *always* an `Object` (with respect to its bounds).  If you want to get any type of numerical reference in there, then you should be also be bound to `Number` (which is the superclass of all of the numerical wrapper classes).

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> void qSort(T[] a, int p, int q)
```

Now, as for the array you'll be passing in...it will have to be an array of `Integer`s instead of `int[]`.

```
Integer[] vals = new Integer[]{5,2,7,3,8,9};
```

The above is possible due to autoboxing, and that `int` is [assignment compatible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) with `Integer`.

Now, if you want to call it, you now pass in the necessary arguments to it.

```
qsort(vals, 0, 10);  // for instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has a **feature called [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)**. Your example would look like

```
qSort( new Integer[]{5,2,7,3,8,9}, p, q)
```

Notice that the array is not based on primitive type `int`, but `int` values inside are "autoboxed" automatically by compiler into `Integer`. Since `Integer` implements `Comparable`, this should work.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with autoboxing.

Comment: It helps to understand how ints get converted to Integers. Since Integer is a class which would work in case of generics

Comment: But not in this context.  With that generic bounding, you could put `String` in that array and it would be just fine.

Comment: Agree.. but look at his question. Also the method is apparently a 'quick sort'

Answer (score 1):

```
qSort( new Integer[] { 5,2,7,3,8,9 }, 0, 5 );
```

The important thing to notice is that the type of the first argument is `Integer[]`, not `int[]`.